# How to download files from a Linux Server with SFTP using pemphrase and Key file?

Tags: linux, sftp

I am trying to download two files from another server using SFTP.

This is the information I have:

- Host: partnerupload.google.com
- Port Number: 19321
- Protocol: SFTP
- Logon Type: Key File Key File Location:
- User (UserName) :
- Passphrase:

I am trying to figure out the correct Linux Command to log into this remote Google Server and download a couple of files. Any Takes?

Answer (score 1):

You're scp incantation will be something along the lines of what I have in my .bashrc file...

```
sshopts="-2 -4 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o Compression=no"
rsacert="~/.ssh/machine.rsa"

scp $sshopts -i $rsacert root@$ip:$1 .
```

Comment: +1 for SCP since there are only 2 files.